# React (Hooks) child component not re-rendering when parent's state changes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-state

I understand this is a somewhat common question but I can't quite find answers here that match my situation.

I have a parent component that is successfully re-rendering whenever I update data using a child component. I also have a separate child component that displays more detailed info and it's this component that I want to re-render so it will display the new, updated information.

I'm passing the data from the parent to the child as props. I understand that changes in props won't cause a re-render, only a change in state will initiate a re-render, but I'm not sure how to do this.

My parent component is called "StudentList" and just displays a list of students.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import { getStudents } from "../queries";
import StudentDetails from "./StudentDetails";


const StudentList = () => {
  const [student, setStudent] = useState("");
  
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(getStudents);
  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error!</p>;

  const handleClick = (student)=> {
    //console.log(student)
  
    setStudent(student);
  };
let filteredStudents = [];

//console.log(data.students)

for(let i = 0; i < data.students.length; i++){
  //console.log(data.students[i].class.name)
  if(data.students[i].class.name === "1FE1"){
    //console.log(data.students[i].name)
    filteredStudents.push(data.students[i])
  }
  
}

//console.log(filteredStudents);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <ul id="student-list">
        {data.students.map((student) => (
          <li key={student.id} onClick={(e) => handleClick(student)}>{student.name}</li>
        ))}
        
      </ul>
      {
        student ? <StudentDetails student={student} /> 
        : <p>No Student Selected</p>
        
      }
    </div>
  );
};

export default StudentList;
```

EditStudent component below.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import StudentDetails from "./StudentDetails";
import { editStudentMutation, getStudentQuery, getStudents } from "../queries/index";


const EditStudent = (props) => {
    console.log(props)
    const [name, setName] = useState(); 
    const [age, setAge] = useState();
    const [test, setTest] = useState();
    const [editStudent] = useMutation(editStudentMutation);

    return (
    
        <form id="edit-student" 
            onSubmit={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                editStudent({
                variables: {
                    id: props.id,
                    name: name,
                    age: age,
                    test1: test
                },
                refetchQueries: [{ query: getStudents}]
                });
            }}>
            <div className="field">
                <label>Student Name:</label>
                <input type="text"
                 value={name}
                 onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}/>
            </div>
            <div className="field">
                <label>Age:</label>
                <input type="text"
                 value={age}
                 onChange={(e) => setAge(e.target.value)}/>
            </div>
            <div className="field">
                <label>Test One:</label>
                <input type="text"
                 value={test}
                 onChange={(e) => setTest(e.target.value)}/>
            </div>
            <button>submit</button>
        </form>
    )
}

export default EditStudent;
```

From StudentList I can click on an individual student and display their info in the "StudentDetails" component.

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getStudentQuery } from "../queries";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import DeleteStudent from "./DeleteStudent"
import EditStudent from "./EditStudent";


const StudentDetails = (props)=> {
    return (
        <div id="student-details" >
            <h2>Name: {props.student.name}</h2>
            <h3>Age: {props.student.age}</h3>
            <h3>Class: {props.student.class.name}</h3>
            <h3>Test 1 Score: {props.student.test1}</h3>
            <DeleteStudent id={props.student.id}/>
            <EditStudent id={props.student.id} />
        </div>
        
    )
    
}

export default StudentDetails;
```

Inside StudentDetails is a third component called "EditStudent" which displays a form to update/edit any student's information.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
//import { getStudents } from "../queries";
import StudentDetails from "./StudentDetails";
import { editStudentMutation, getStudentQuery, getStudents } from "../queries/index";


const EditStudent = (props) => {
    console.log(props)
    const [name, setName] = useState(); 
    const [age, setAge] = useState();
    const [test, setTest] = useState();
    const [editStudent] = useMutation(editStudentMutation);

    return (
    
        <form id="edit-student" 
            onSubmit={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                editStudent({
                variables: {
                    id: props.id,
                    name: name,
                    age: age,
                    test1: test
                },
                refetchQueries: [{ query: getStudents}]
                });
            }}>
            <div className="field">
                <label>Student Name:</label>
                <input type="text"
                 value={name}
                 onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}/>
            </div>
            <div className="field">
                <label>Age:</label>
                <input type="text"
                 value={age}
                 onChange={(e) => setAge(e.target.value)}/>
            </div>
            <div className="field">
                <label>Test One:</label>
                <input type="text"
                 value={test}
                 onChange={(e) => setTest(e.target.value)}/>
            </div>
            <button>submit</button>
        </form>
    )
}

export default EditStudent;
```

As I mentioned, EditStudent successfully which then makes StudentList re-render. My problem has been getting StudentDetails to re-render. I've been trying various different things with useEffect to force a re-render but I'm not sure in which component I would need to do this. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: "I understand that changes in props won't cause a re-render" Sure they will.

Comment: Please share the code of `StudentList` which renders the `StudentDetails` component.

Comment: @ArnasSavickas My bad! I shared the EditStudent Code instead of the StudentList. I'll update this

Comment: Most likely `StudentList` children components are not rendered because its state doesn't change.

Comment: You're not emmiting anything from the EditStudent component to the parent components

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković You mean I would somehow need to pass the info from EditStudent to StudentList?

Comment: @user14593966 Yes, currently StudentList component never gets notified of the changes

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković I see. I'm looking into that.